# change height of right border

Tags: html, css

My right border is 100% height:

```
border-right:1px solid #000000;
```

[image]

I'd like to make it shorter:

[image]

Is it achievable using CSS without changing the height of the div? I need div to be 100% height and only change that border.

Comment: margin on top and bottom might can help

Comment: @Nimmi only if the element you apply the right border to is part of another one that has the top and bottom borders...

Comment: Oh Right agree...than margin could not do the proper trick :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a **pseudo element** to replace the right border. As you can choose the size/position of it you can simulate a border with it :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Qmp8s/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div {
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    background:gold;
    position:relative;
    border-top:10px solid grey;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
div:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:20%;
    right:0;
    width:2px;
    height:60%;
    background:#000;
}
```

Supports IE8 see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements)

Comment: This is clever. The only consideration is IE8 support. But I think that's a minor complaint. You sir get an upvote!

Comment: @InternalFX IE8 supports pseudo elements with only one `:` see here : http://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements

Comment: Well then your gold. Sorry, only have one upvote to give.

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible with pseudo elements. I don't know if this is what you're looking for:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psL3r/2/)

`

```
div:after{
  content:'';
  height:150px;
  width:200px;
  border-right:1px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top:30px;

}
```

Comment: your fiddle is empty...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anyway to do this with plain css.

You will need to create the effect using more than one div.

Comment: there are css workarounds for this

Comment: don't see the OP mentioning they didn't want to create another div...

Comment: @web-tiki has a point. Didn't consider pseudo elements.

Comment: It can be done in CSS using :after pseudo CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you separated it into 2 `div`'s and gave the outer div the top and bottom borders, and just specified a smaller height and a margin for the inner div, it could work:

```css
#outer {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

#inner {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:10px;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ4MX/)**

Comment: Padding doesn't break up a border.

Comment: true that! updated my answer now...

Answer (score 0):

```
.cont {
  height : 200px;
  background: gray;
  position:relative;
}
.hr {
  width:2px;
  height:90%;
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top: 5%;
}
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMzM8/2/) for above code

Comment: nothing showing in your fiddle... you may want to add borders...

Comment: Check extreme right black border.
I have updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KMzM8/2/ with gray background and red border

Comment: think you forgot to add it back in your answer...

Comment: Yes, now added again. thanks.